# How to resolve conflicts between Derived Custom Control Class and EventHandlers in Form1.cs

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public CustomListView()
    {

    }
    private bool ContextAllowed = false;

    public override ContextMenuStrip ContextMenuStrip
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ContextMenuStrip;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ContextMenuStrip = value;
            base.ContextMenuStrip.Opening += ContextMenuStrip_Open;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ListViewHitTestInfo test = HitTest(e.X, e.Y); //perform a hit test
            if (test.Item != null) //if it hits an item, display the popup bar
            {
                ContextAllowed = true;
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextAllowed = false; //close the menu
        }
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    private void ContextMenuStrip_Open(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ContextAllowed)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**
The above code is for a class called CustomListView. It is a custom control, whose purpose is to allow me to right-click a row and perform functions with that row. I succesfully built it as a dll, added it to the toolbox, and am using it on my form. I am able to fill it with info just like a regular ListView, but ANY right-click functionality with the ContextMenuStrip is just not working.

**Attempts at Solutions:**
I HAVE assigned the ContextMenuStrip to the CustomListView control. I think the problem is the EventHandlers in the CustomListView class (i.e. the OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp) are not being used. Instead, the "other" event handers with the same name are being used in Form1.cs, that naturally contain no code.

Should I move the EventHandlers in the CustomListView class to Form1.cs? How can I get the EventHandlers in the CustomListView class to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

- A listview has no ContextMenuStrip by default.  Which means you have to make sure it has one before you can use it.
- After you set the boolean allowing it to be displayed you have to call the `Show()` method.  In fact you could probably dispense with the boolean and just use the `Show()` and `Close()` methods.

  ```
  public class CustomListView : ListView
  {
      public CustomListView()
      {
          cms.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]{ new ToolStripLabel("Test1"),new ToolStripLabel("Test2")});
          ContextMenuStrip = cms;
      }
      private bool ContextAllowed = false;
      private ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();

      public override ContextMenuStrip ContextMenuStrip
      {
          get
          {
              return base.ContextMenuStrip;
          }
          set
          {
              base.ContextMenuStrip = value;
              base.ContextMenuStrip.Opening += ContextMenuStrip_Open;
          }
      }

      protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
          {
              ListViewHitTestInfo test = HitTest(e.X, e.Y); //perform a hit test
              if (test.Item != null) //if it hits an item, display the popup bar
              {
                  ContextAllowed = true;
                  ContextMenuStrip.Show();
              }
          }
          base.OnMouseDown(e);
      }
      protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
          {
              ContextAllowed = false; //close the menu
          }
          base.OnMouseUp(e);
      }

      private void ContextMenuStrip_Open(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
      {
          if (!ContextAllowed)
          {
              e.Cancel = true;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Okay understood about the booleans. How does the compiler reconcile the event handlers in the class itself, and those that are accessible from the designer in visual studio?

Comment: @t72 - If I'm not mistaken the handlers for a particular event are in a list and get run in the order they are added.  Since the one in your class is added first it will run first.

Comment: One clarification: Is the ContextMenuStrip_Open method even necessary, if I'm already opening the MenuStrip in the MOuseDown/Mouseup? Currently redoing the code to make those changes, I also noticed I'm getting a NullReferenceException in CustomListView at some point. ALSO: I notice this happens when I don't click anything with either mouse button on the form.

Comment: I think for some reason I'm not passing in the ContextMenuStrip correctly. I have it set in the Designer in VS, also tried adding it to Form1_Load.

Comment: @t72 - Did you try following the example in my code?  Notice the ContextMenuStrip is set as a private field.  You can set the items however you like and have code inside the class to handle them.  The default constructor can be used as I have done.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I'm still having problems. I've tried both creating a new CMS in the class itself (as you did), and also setting it in the form (binding CMS to the ListView, of course). I still continue to get a problem immediately on starting, though the CustomList displays fine, holds data fine, etc. Also, strangely, now if I change some detail of the customlist view (ex. commented out 'customListView1.View = View.Details') the designer crashes. I think these are all related somehow but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @t72 - You'll probably have to submit a new question with the new code, since this is going quite a bit off topic.